# Easiest way to import list of locations for web app?

Tags: json, mobile, web, mean-stack

I'm working on a mobile application that requires a list of every city in the US.

I considered using a JSON file but it is way to big. How can I easily implement locations in my application?

Comment: You shall consider gathering the cities names filtered by state. Or, you could also wait the user type something in the city input box and than filter by that.

Comment: I want users to be able to search for other users in a city and to group users by city.

Comment: Actually, I'd want to pre-load matching cities as users type them in.

Comment: The OR part here I meant : When the user has typed in "new" (so lets say, at least 3 characters) then you gather all the cities containing or starting with "new" and you list them. This is done using "AJAX".